# UpdatePanel refreshing with <input type="image"> but not type="button

Tags: asp.net, html, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel control in my ASP.NET application (actually several, but that's not the concern).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
...More code here
```

Inside the panel, there exists an `asp:Table` object:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblGIFs" runat="server"></asp:table>
```

This table gets programmatically generated via some code from codebehind:

```
TableRow htr = new TableRow();
TableCell htc = new TableCell();
...<snip>
tblGIFs.Rows.Add(htr)
```

And that's all fine, except in one of the cells I am trying to add a button (with an image):

```
htc3.Text = "<input ID=\""+ii.Value+"\" OnClick = \"btnGIFSearch(this)\" type=\"image\" value=\"/Image/Fiu.png\" />";
```

When this image is clicked, the `onclick` fires fine, but the entire `UpdatePanel` gets refreshed (and consequentually, the `asp:Table` disappears).

If I use a `type="button"`, it works completely fine and there's no issue with refreshing/losing the content in the table.

I've run the page with breakpoints on every location that I'm touching the table from codebehind to no avail, there's really nothing more that I can see that could cause the `UpdatePanel` to be cleared programtically.

Anyone seen similar behavior with these tags/controls and any idea of a resolution? A workaround is obviously using `type=button` and just styling the button, but I rather not do that if I can get `type=image` behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with dynamically created controls.

Answer (score 9):

An input type "image" is like a submit button. It's submitting the form, because that's what they do. If your code-behind is not rebuilding the table in the case of a postback that you don't expect, the table won't be rebuilt, and hence disappear (keep in mind whenever you build controls dynamically, you must do so every request). If you don't want the button to postback, have your OnClick handler return false to cancel the post. If you DO want the button to postback, then you have a different problem, probably related to using dynamic controls incorrectly.

Comment: I wanted to add that whenever you are having trouble with an UpdatePanel, the first troubleshooting thing you should do is to REMOVE IT. Chances are, you have a regular ole ASP.NET problem, and the UpdatePanel is taking the blame. Posts within updatepanels work exactly like regular postbacks (aside from being done via ajax), so your form really should work the same without one than it does with one. That's definitely good practice, anyway.

Comment: Hi, I know how `UpdatePanel` works, and your answer has basically nothing to do with my question. The `onclick` handler is just a dummy alert box right now (and it has had `return false;` since I first created it, because it's meant to be dry-wired and not postback).

Comment: Um, I understood the question perfectly. You didn't say your click handler returned false. Also, no, actually it does not return false because there's no return statement in your OnClick attribute, so the return value isn't being re-returned to the browser :) Thanks for the downvote, sheesh.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with why it only exhibits this kind of behavior when using `type=image` and not `type=button`. And keep taking downvotes personally, because they are not (your answer was not useful).

Comment: Inputs of type=button do not post the form they are in natively by the browser. Inputs of type=image do. That's what I said, in not so many words. Have you even tried what I suggested?

Comment: Yeah, he's right. You should try to listen: you are confusing type=button with type=submit. And you should definitely give him the answer rather than downgrade it.